Ubuntu 22 stopped booting
Ubuntu 22 stopped booting suddenly. Yesterday worked fine and the only different thing is the updates done in the system (do not really remember what) . Now it stops at "/dev/sdb5: clean".
Recovery mode also freezes at Finished Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
USB live freezes also at the Ubuntu logo screen after like 15 minutes. It is somehow a dead end for me.
Any help would be appreciated. It is a custom machine with an old Gigabyte Motherboard.

Live USB safe graphics option results to [19.162262] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

This question is similar to: "dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
